# Business process exception for entity having invalid status, what http status to return in REST API

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

Let's say I want to model process in my RESTful API whereas `Campaign` can be activated only if it is in status `DRAFT`.

I can define MVC mapping `/campaigns/{id}/activate` and inside method I can have

```
if (!campaign.isDraft()) {
    throw new InvalidStatusException(campaign.getStatus());
}
```

To what HTTP status should I map `InvalidStatusException`?

I am under impression, **500** Interval Server Error is not acceptable

Answer (score 0):

[409 (CONFLICT)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8) looks appropriate. You may also use [412 (PRECONDITION FAILED)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-4.2) or [422 (UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2).

Answer (score 0):

Since the bussiness domain rule is violated (if I understood correctly - campaign cannot be activated twice), I think `403 (Forbidden)` in conjunction with human readable error text message (like "Campaign must be Draft") should be good.